# stackexchange/circuitlab-bug or linux/firefox-bug?

Tags: bug

I submitted a bug report for Ubuntu in parallel: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1177236

---

I think it is a Linux/Firefox bug, but I want to double check here. **Sometimes** while scrolling some (not all) of the circuits diagram look funny. Most of the time this is just a glitch and it instantly disappears before you can blink your eyes, but this morning I managed to capture what is happening:

[image]

It should of course look like this:

[image]

My question is:

- Do I register a bug with Ubuntu / Mozilla or
- Do I register a bug with StackExchange / CircuitLab?

Environment:

[Invert a 555 Astable Output Signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/68413/invert-a-555-astable-output-signal)

```
€ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:        13.04

€ apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 20.0+build1-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 20.0+build1-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 20.0+build1-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: It displays correctly with me, and I'm using Chrome 26 on Windows 7 in Eindhoven :)

Comment: So Eindhoven can't be the problem then. Welcome back!

Comment: I think so, yes :) Thanks!

Comment: I can't quite replicate it in either FF/Chrome, but I can confirm that these are simply PNG images generated by CircuitLab, and pulled in by StackEx and hosted on imgur.

Comment: Noticing the same behaviour on other sites too. Not alone with .png images, also with .jpg.